# undefined method `friend' for nil:NilClass Rails Pry issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, zip, iteration, each

I'm using ruby on rails building a friend to friend relationship. I've encountered something odd, where pry works but the server doesn't. Not sure how to deal with this one.

I have gotten an undefined method `friend' for nil:NilClass,` referring to  `<% if user.username != friendship.friend.username %>` but,

```
    <% @users.zip(@friendships).each do |user, friendship| %>
      <% if user != current_user %>

        <% binding.pry %>
        <% if user.username != friendship.friend.username %>
```

i put a pry above to see whats happening and got

```
     [1] pry(#<#<Class:0x007fbc2dda3040>>)> friendship.friend.username
     User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
     => "Remington_langosh25129"
     [2] pry(#<#<Class:0x007fbc2dda3040>>)> user.username
     => “Remington_langosh25129”
```

anyone have ideas why it works in pry but not in rails?

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of working on this, the array users and friendships are of different lengths, so this has to be solved as follows,

In the models a scope that makes an array of the current user's friend ids with an addition of the current user's id, will solve the issue.

model: `scope :nonfriends, -> (user) { where.not(id: user.friends.ids << user.id) }`

controller:  `@users = User.nonfriends(current_user)`

view:  `<% @users.each do |user| %>`